# Fasterxml: can't parse subtype from json

Tags: java, json, fasterxml

***Problem:***

Fasterxml can construct an object when it use abstraction in setters. See code below

`Can not construct instance of CarState, problem: abstract types either need to be mapped to concrete types, have custom deserializer, or be instantiated with additional type information`

***Code:***

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Inheritance(strategy= InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public interface IState {}

public class BusState implements IState{}

//register subtype in mapper
mapper.registerSubtypes(BusState .class);   

public interface Car {
  public void setState(IState state); 
}

@Entity
public class Bus implements Car {

  private BusState state;

  public void getState(BusState state) { //Seems fasterxml doesn't use this method, instead it use Car.setState
    this.state = state;
  }
}
```

I can create two different methods in `Bus` class: one for setting`IState` and one for `BusState`. But it looks ugly.

***Question:***

How  can I make fasterxml to construct `Bus`-object correctly?

Comment: Please post a sample JSON.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis see EDIT section of my question

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I find the reason. I solve the problem by deleting `setState` method in `Car` interface